# MigraDoc Output to RTF different than PDF

Tags: pdf, rtf, migradoc

I ran the same doc, at the same time, to both rtf and pdf and found that the two renders don't look the same. The Render to rtf is about what I expect whereas the pdf is not.

I would prefer to output to pdf. Can someone tell me where I am doing wrong?

I have included what I think is relevant and necessary. Any help is appreciated.

[image: PDF Version]

[image: RTF Version]

```
 public static Document CreateWorkOrderPDF2(Document document, string filename, string WorkOrderHeader, string myMessage)
    {
        Section section = document.AddSection();
        section.PageSetup.PageFormat = PageFormat.Letter;

        section.PageSetup.StartingNumber = 1;

        /*Section Margins
         ****************/
        section.PageSetup.LeftMargin = 40;
        section.PageSetup.TopMargin = 100;
        section.PageSetup.RightMargin = 40;
        section.PageSetup.BottomMargin = 40;

        /*HeaderFooter
         *************/
        HeaderFooter header = section.Headers.Primary;
        header.Format.Font.Size = 16;
        header.Format.Font.Color = Colors.DarkBlue;
        //header.AddParagraph();


        /*Logo Image
         ***********/
        MigraDoc.DocumentObjectModel.Shapes.Image headerImage = header.AddImage("../../Fonts/castorgate.regular.png");
        headerImage.Width = "2cm";
        headerImage.Top = 0;
        //headerImage.WrapFormat.DistanceTop = 300;
        headerImage.WrapFormat.Style = WrapStyle.Through;

        /*Blue Work Order Line
        **********************/
        TextFrame BlueWorkOrderLine = header.AddTextFrame();
        BlueWorkOrderLine.Top = 40;
        //BlueWorkOrderLine.WrapFormat.DistanceTop = 40;
        BlueWorkOrderLine.Left = 0;
        BlueWorkOrderLine.Width = 300;
        BlueWorkOrderLine.WrapFormat.Style = WrapStyle.Through;

        Paragraph headerParagraph = BlueWorkOrderLine.AddParagraph(WorkOrderHeader);
        headerParagraph.Format.Font.Name = "Consolas";
        headerParagraph.Format.Font.Color = Colors.Blue;
        headerParagraph.Format.Borders.Width = .5;

        /*Vertical Text TextFrame
        *************************/
        TextFrame WorkOrderVerticalTextFrame = header.AddTextFrame();
        WorkOrderVerticalTextFrame.Orientation = TextOrientation.Downward;
        WorkOrderVerticalTextFrame.Left = 550;
        WorkOrderVerticalTextFrame.Width = 10;
        WorkOrderVerticalTextFrame.Top = 0;
        WorkOrderVerticalTextFrame.Height = 150;
        WorkOrderVerticalTextFrame.WrapFormat.Style = WrapStyle.Through;

        Paragraph WorkOrderVerticalParagraph = WorkOrderVerticalTextFrame.AddParagraph();
        WorkOrderVerticalParagraph.Format.Alignment = ParagraphAlignment.Left;
        WorkOrderVerticalParagraph.Format.Font.Name = "Consolas";
        WorkOrderVerticalParagraph.Format.Font.Size = 8;
        WorkOrderVerticalParagraph.AddText(WorkOrderHeader);
        WorkOrderVerticalParagraph.Format.Borders.Width = .5;

        /*Estimate Records Paragraph
         ***************************/
        Paragraph EstRecordsParagraph = section.AddParagraph(myMessage);
        EstRecordsParagraph.Format.Font.Size = 10;
        EstRecordsParagraph.Format.Font.Color = Colors.DarkRed;
        EstRecordsParagraph.Format.Borders.Width = .5;
        EstRecordsParagraph.Format.RightIndent = 0;

        Paragraph renderDate = section.AddParagraph();
        renderDate = section.AddParagraph("Work Order Generated: ");
        renderDate.AddDateField();

        return document;
    }

private void pdf5(string SaveFilePath, string WorkOrderHeader, string myMessage)
    {
        // Create a MigraDoc document
        Document document = CreateDocument3();
        document = CreateWorkOrderPDF2(document, SaveFilePath, WorkOrderHeader, myMessage);

        MigraDoc.DocumentObjectModel.IO.DdlWriter.WriteToFile(document, "MigraDoc.mdddl");

        PdfDocumentRenderer renderer = new PdfDocumentRenderer(true, PdfSharp.Pdf.PdfFontEmbedding.Always);
        renderer.Document = document;

        renderer.RenderDocument();

        // Save the document...
        string PDFSaveFilePath = string.Concat(SaveFilePath, ".pdf");
        string RTFSaveFilePath = string.Concat(SaveFilePath, ".rtf");


        try
        {
            renderer.PdfDocument.Save(PDFSaveFilePath);

            //Make RTF Version
            miRtf_Click(document, RTFSaveFilePath);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show($"{ex}");
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates a RTF file from the current document.
    /// </summary>
    private void miRtf_Click(Document document, string SaveFilePath)
    {
        RtfDocumentRenderer rtf = new RtfDocumentRenderer();
        rtf.Render(document, SaveFilePath, null);

        Process.Start(SaveFilePath);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You set `WrapStyle.Through` for both Image and TextFrame, so overlapping is not unexpected. Both renderers should yield the same result, but I'm not sure which one is wrong.

I do not understand why you use `WrapStyle.Through` in this case. You can simply add the Image and the text to a single paragraph using a linebreak after the image. Or use one paragraph for the image, one paragraph for the text. No need to have a TextFrame and no need to change the WrapFormat for the Image if I understand your intentions correctly.

Comment: There is vertical text on the right hand side which is effected by the wrap style of the image so my plan was to "WrapStyle.Through" and then manually plot the other elements. What surprised me was that rtf did exactly what I expected and pdf didn't.  "BlueWorkOrderLine.Top" seems to work with rtf, but not in pdf